# How can I provide mobility to motes in cooja?

Tags: contiki, mobility

I would like to assign mobility to motes already deployed. The deployment method can be anyone among the given options given in cooja. Can anyone please tell me how to assign mobility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there currently is no working mobility plugin. Currently I see the following options:

- You can use the test-script to move your motes around. This needs some looking in to the Cooja code, but shouldn't be too difficult. Especially when taking the [examples from the wiki](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/wiki/Using-Cooja-Test-Scripts-to-Automate-Simulations#tips-and-tricks) as staring point.
- You can get the [mobilty plugin](http://sourceforge.net/p/contikiprojects/code/HEAD/tree/sics.se/mobility/) working again. Shouldn't be too much work either and lots of people will thank you. Adjusting the name-spaces should get you quite far, but it might be a bit more.
- If you can derive connection-properties from your mobility-model, you can use [realsim](https://github.com/cmorty/realsim) feed these into Cooja.